# Firefox paste stopped working

Tags: linux, firefox, arch-linux, i3-window-manager

Good day guys, I've woken up today and realize that I can't paste into firefox. I've somehow fixed other GUI apps but the firefox still won't paste anything into it.

UPDATE: Everything started working now. Except Firefox.

Comment: What do you mean by "stopped working"? What did you change? Was it the urxvt config? What shortcut are you using when you try to paste in a GUI application? Have you tried others? Please be more specific ;)

Comment: I am using CTRL + V and I also tried Paste by right-click context menu. URXVT is fine don't touch it. I've tried a lot of them no one worked. By stopped working I meant that at evening it worked by waking up in a morning and turning PC it is not working. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You changed nothing and it stopped working? Seems weird. Anyway, you should check out the [Clipboard page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/clipboard) from the Arch Wiki, maybe you cannot paste because the content is not in the right clipboard (you should also try the middle mouse click to see if this works).

Comment: There is nothing on wiki that will help me. But I found that only GTK applications won't accept paste instruction. But QT application and CLI are working just fine.